# Dependency failed while installing php-gd on Centos 6

Tags: php, linux, centos

I am trying to install `php-gd` on my centos 6 machine but I am getting this error ... can anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.nayatel.com
 * epel: mirrors.nayatel.com
 * extras: mirrors.nayatel.com
 * remi: remi.schlundtech.de
 * remi-php56: remi.schlundtech.de
 * remi-safe: remi.schlundtech.de
 * rpmforge: ftp.heanet.ie
 * updates: mirrors.nayatel.com
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.26-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1 for package: php-gd-5.6.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.3()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gd-last.x86_64 0:2.2.3-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.5()(64bit) for package: gd-last-2.2.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: gd-last-2.2.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libwebp.so.5()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libwebp.so.5
libwebp-0.4.3-3.el6.x86_64

# yum info libwebp
Installed Packages
Name        : libwebp
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 0.4.3
Release     : 3.el6
Size        : 659 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : epel
Summary     : Library and tools for the WebP graphics format
URL         : http://webmproject.org/
License     : BSD
Description : WebP is an image format that does lossy compression of digital
            : photographic images. WebP consists of a codec based on VP8, and a
            : container based on RIFF. Webmasters, web developers and browser
            : developers can use WebP to compress, archive and distribute digital
            : images more efficiently.
```

So should work.
Please check **remi-release** and **epel-release** match the centOS version you are running, and that you don't have any other version of **libwebp** installed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I am really struggling with this as you suggested when I run the first command I get this error `# rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libwebp.so.5
error: file /usr/lib64/libwebp.so.5: No such file or directory` and for `yum info libwebp` i get this `Error: No matching Packages to list` ... I am not sure what could be the problem

Comment: So i think there are no versions of `libwebp` installed

Comment: Check for "exclude" line in yum configuration files. Else, download it and install it manually.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue updating to PHP 5.6, but found that libwebp could be installed from the EPEL Centos 6 repo:

```
yum install epel-release
```

Might want to check this is disabled by default in

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```

Then

```
yum --enablerepo remi,epel install gd-last
```

installed the gd-last package..

and I went back to my original command (updating to php 5.6)

```
yum --enablerepo remi,remi-php56 update php*
```